# How do we solve for $\frac {\partial x} {\partial \|x\| }$ ?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Here $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\|.\|$ is the standard $l2$ norm. Is this the element-wise inverse of $\frac {\partial \|x\| } {\partial x}$ ? I tried to work this out element wise but nothing came of it.

Comment: Remark: the derivative $\frac{\partial x}{\partial ||x||}$ would be a vector and $\frac{\partial ||x||}{\partial x}$ would be a scalar

Comment: $ \dfrac {\partial \|x\|} {\partial  x} = \dfrac { x } { \|x\| }$ which is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$ right ? I am pretty sure about this.

Comment: what do you mean for $\frac{||x||}{x}$?

Comment: See edited comment above. Sorry for the typo.